# What are the initial and boundary conditions for this problem?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, heat-equation, finite-differences

I'm trying to solve a heat diffusion problem (with finite difference approximation) with conditions stated like this:

> A 10cm thin plate is initially at $120^{\circ}C$ then suddenly the
>   right side is dropped to $0^{\circ}C$ while the left surface is kept
>   insulated. Given $\alpha$, find the temperature distribution at $10$
>   and $20$ seconds.

I'm supposed to use the Crank-Nicolson approximation, but I'm not sure how to construct matrices $A$ and $b$ to solve $Ax=b$.

I'm pretty sure the "left surface insulated" means (in MATLAB notation) :

```
A(1,:) = [1, -1, zeros(1,Nx-2)];
b(1) = 0;
```

So for each time step, $T_1 - T_2 = 0$, i.e. there is no heat flow.

But I'm not sure how to interpret "right side suddenly dropped to 0". I did it like this:

```
Solution = zeros(Nt, Nx); % Time steps x Spatial nodes
Solution(1,:) = [ones(1,Nx-1)*120, 0]; % so the initial distribution is [120, 120, ... , 120, 0]
```

Is this correct? And does the question imply right surface is **kept** at $0^{\circ}C$? So I keep solving the indermediate steps as :

```
A(Nx,:) = [zeros(1,Nx-1), 1];
b(Nx) = 0;
```

i.e. at each time step $T_{(N_x)} = 0$.

Does this look correct? The problem is, I get an unstable solution, whereas CN method is said to be "unconditionally stable". The solution oscillates, and also nodes very close to right hand side become $<0$ so there is a sharp jump at the right hand side. See:
[image]

What is surprising is, as I increase `Nx`, therefore impose a finer grid, the solution gets worse, opposite of what I expected. This screenshot is from my trial with 100 points, and `T_right = 10` instead of `0`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

As long as I understand you should not have a jump. What is your grid step?
In general the finer the grid, the better the result, but numerically you cannot refine it forever.

Assume the problem on an interval $[a,b]$.

The initial condition is that all plate has $120^\circ$ at $t_0$.

Insulated boundary condition for heat diffusion problem means no flow heat flow, i.e.  $u_x(a,t)=0$.

The other side is a different story, you have to use the [Newton's Law of Cooling](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/TheHeatEquation.aspx) ([see also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling)), which (for the second end) says

$$-K_0 u_x(b,t)=H (u(b,t) - u(b,t_0))$$
where $K_0$ is thermal conductivity (in $u_t = k u_{xx}$ you have thermal diffusion $k=\frac{K_0}{c\rho}$, $c$- specific heat, $\rho$- mass density) and $H>0$ is some coefficient.

In your case it looks like, you should use the following BC
 $$u_x(b,t)=\beta (u(b,t) - 120^\circ)$$
for some $\beta$ (not sure if the $\alpha$ you talking about is $k$ or this $\beta$).

For implementation example look
http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/class/ME448/notes/pdf/Alt_BC_slides.pdf